# QBResponseException: Entity you are looking for was not found in loading userlist?

Tags: android-studio, video-processing, quickblox

i am doing video chat now in my app, i found some code in the Quickblox for android, i am not able to get the userlist for chat i am getting the following error message like "QBResponseException : Entity you are looking for was not found", i am stuck this for a day, i went through lot of search but i am not able to find any suitable solution for it, can anyone help me with this.

Below i have attached my code:

```
QBPagedRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
        requestBuilder.setPerPage(getResources().getInteger(10));

        List<String> tags = new LinkedList<>();
        tags.add("webrtcusers");

        QBUsers.getUsersByTags(tags, requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> qbUsers, Bundle bundle)

            {
                System.out.println("INSIDE LISt");
                showProgress(false);

                users.clear();
                users.addAll(DataHolder.createUsersList(qbUsers));
                initUsersList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException exc) {
                showProgress(false);
               /* Toaster.longToast("Error while loading users");*/
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while loading users",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onError()"+exc.toString());
            }
        });
```

Response goes to OnError with above exception. It tells me to look at the QuickBlox at dashboard Admin panel to look for correct Account Key, guys i am counting on you to get grid of these.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the requested resource could not be found. So check that you really have users with tag "webrtcusers" in your app.